# how to import ed25519 root ca into Keychain Access MacOS?

Tags: go, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, ed25519

```bash
openssl req  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out root.crt -keyout root.key
```

this works fine, but if i use ed25519:

```bash
openssl req  -newkey ed25519 -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out root.crt -keyout root.key
```

Keychain Access could not import root.crt, err code : -25257 (unknown format)

is there anyway to use ed25519?

```bash
openssl verify -CAfile <(cat root.crt inter.crt) server.crt client.crt
server.crt: OK
client.crt: OK
```

.crt file works fine.